# Is there a way to simplify this further before deriving?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm supposed to find the second order derivative at $x=\pi/16$ for $0<x<\pi/8$. I was wondering if there was a way to simplify this equation further than just factoring out 196 from the square root and setting a variable equal to 4x before deriving to make things easier?

$y=\sec^2(4x)(196\cos^2(4x)+392+196\sec^2(4x))^{1/2}$

Comment: Hint: $a^2+2ab+b^2=(a+b)^2$.

Comment: Look closer at that thing under the square root. Isn't it a square of something nice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, factor out $196=14^2$ and use the fact that $\sec^2(4x) = 1/\cos^2(4x)$ from under the square root:

$y = {14\over\cos^2(4x)}\sqrt{cos^2(4x)+2+1/cos^2(4x)}$

Then use the identity $a^2+2ab+b^2 = (a+b)^2$ for the expression under the square root.